# Limitations or Guidelines - Using If else loop in SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

Whether the below structure is possible in SharePoint Designer Workflow (On Changed)? or Are there any guidelines to implement the same in efficient way?

```
          if(condition 1)
          Action 1
          else if(condition 2)
          Action 2
          else if(condition 3)
          Action 3
          else if(condition 4)
          Action 4
          else
          Action 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using 2013 there is a an option for else if branches.

[image]

Comment: whether this is not possible in SPD 2010 workflows?

Comment: I can't speak to SPD 2010 as we skipped 2010 in our environment and went directly from 2007 to 2013.  That said, in 2007 you could build a similar sort of logic without actually using an else statement.  For example, you could have an IF statement run and if the condition was true you could perform your action and then immediately thereafter perform a stop workflow action.  Basically what this would do is run through your IF statements until it came to one which tested true, run that action, stop the workflow and not run any other subsequent condition/actions.

Comment: Thanks Nate. It worked fine. Actually i tried in SPD 2013 with Platform Type SharePoint 2010 Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do similar thing in SPD 2010.

Comment: The Platform Type i selected was SharePoint 2010 Workflow. it worked. Thanks